# Cannot get Get-SQLAgent server Properties

Tags: sql-server, powershell

This command always ends with an exception on every server I have tested. I am not an admin, but it does not say it is a permission issue. Should this work? How can I get this to work?

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 11.0.7001.0 (X64)
>$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
5.1.14409.1018
>(Get-Module -Name SqlServer).Version.ToString()
21.1.18068
```

The command is:

```
(Get-SqlAgent -ServerInstance DBSERVER02).Properties

...
Name       : MaximumHistoryRows
Value      : -1
Type       : System.Int32
Writable   : True
Readable   : True
Expensive  : False
Dirty      : False
Retrieved  : True
IsNull     : False
Enabled    : False
Required   : False
Attributes : {}

Name       : MaximumJobHistoryRows
Value      : 0
Type       : System.Int32
Writable   : True
Readable   : True
Expensive  : False
Dirty      : False
Retrieved  : True
IsNull     : False
Enabled    : False
Required   : False
Attributes : {}
```

> An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: An exception
>   occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + (Get-SqlAgent -ServerInstance DBSERVER02).properties
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.SqlSe...pertyEnumerator:PropertyEnumerator) [],
>   RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration

Update:

It appears that `Properties` and `TargetServerGroups` are the culprits.

```
>$a = Get-SqlAgent -ServerInstance DBSERVER02; $a | Get-Member -Type Properties |% { try { $name = $_.name; $a.$name | out-null } catch { $name + " doesn't work: " + $_ } }
Properties doesn't work: An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch..
TargetServerGroups doesn't work: The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the collection: "An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement
or batch.".
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea to do that -- enumerating *all* properties results in SMO firing a ton of commands at the server to get various exotic bits of information. You should probably restrict the code to retrieving only that data you're actually interested in. To see where it fails, you'd need to hook up Profiler and spot the failing command(s). FWIW, this code worksforme (tm) against both a local SQL Server 2017 instance and a remote SQL Server 2012 instance (using `21.0.17240`).

Comment: To see what property/properties are the actual problem, this should do: `$a = Get-SqlAgent -ServerInstance .; $a | Get-Member -Type Properties |% { try { $name = $_.name; $a.$name | out-null } catch { $name + " doesn't work: " + $_ } }` (disclaimer: not tested since they all work for me).